# How to create one to one relationship T-SQL for EntityFramework code first

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Company (
    Id uniqueidentifier primary key not null, 
    CompanyName nvarchar(100) not null)
GO

CREATE TABLE Feature (
    Id uniqueidentifier primary key not null, 
    CompanyId uniqueidentifier not null, 
    Feature1 bit not null, 
    Feature2 bit not null)
GO
```

How to make one to one relation by CompanyId field on database and EF Code First side with configuration files

The classes:

```
    public class Company
{
    private Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class Feature
{
    private Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    public virtual Guid Id
    {
        get { return id; }

        set { id = value; }
    }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Feature1 { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Feature2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make a real one-to-one relation in EF with these tables because it requires unique index on `CompanyId` column and EF doesn't support unique indices yet. Currently the only way to get a real one-to-one relation is to use primary key of dependent table (in your case `Feature.Id`) as foreign key to principal table.

You can cheat. Just use it as one-to-many (Company can have many features) and if you have unique index in the database you will receive exception if another feature tries to associate with already used company.